# racket: (evaluate t lst)

Tags: eval, racket, arithmetic-expressions

I implemented a function that takes an arithmetic expression and returns the value:

```
; an arithmetic expression (t) is one of the following:
; - a number
; - a list of the form '(a operator b) where a and b are arithmetic expressions
; arithmetic expression -> number

; computes the value of the arithmetic expression

(define (eval t)
  (cond
    [(number? t) t]
    [else ((cond
            [(equal? (second t) '+) +]
            [(equal? (second t) '-) -]
            [(equal? (second t) '*) *]
            [(equal? (second t) '/) /])
           (eval (first t)) (eval (third t)))]))
```

It works perfectly, but obviously it can't take constants. So what I'm trying to do is to extend the program such that it works for something like:

```
(eval '(1 + (3 * x)) (make-const 'x 3)                     -> 10
(eval '((3 - x) * y) ((make-const 'x 1) (make-const 'y 2)) -> 4
(eval '(1 + (y * x)) (make-const 'x 3)                     -> "error"
```

My idea was to define a struct:

```
(define struct const (symbol number))


(define (eval. t x)
  (cond
    [(number? t) t]
    [(symbol?  t) ???]
    [else ((cond
            [(equal? (second t) '+) +]
            [(equal? (second t) '-) -]
            [(equal? (second t) '*) *]
            [(equal? (second t) '/) /])
           (eval. (first t) lst) (eval. (third t) lst))]))
```

Can anyone tell me if I am headed in the right direction and maybe give me a hint? It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that your examples are slightly wrong:

```
(eval '(1 + (3 * x)) (make-const 'x 3)
; you need a closing parenthesis

(eval '((3 - x) * y) ((make-const 'x 1) (make-const 'y 2))
; same as above. also, ((make-const 'x 1) (make-const 'y 2)) doesn't make
; sense. Do you mean (list (make-const 'x 1) (make-const 'y 2))
```

Anyway, there are two ways to do this.

The first way is to make `eval` has two phases: the first phase is to *substitute* all variables first. If things go well, you would get an expression with no identifier back. The second step is to call your first version of `eval` (where I will refer to as `eval-helper`).

```
; eval :: expr, listof const -> number
(define (eval t vars)
  (eval-helper (subst-all t vars)))
```

Indeed, the difficult part is to get `subst-all` correct. To simplify things, you might want to write a function named `subst` which substitutes only one identifier at a time. This could be done by a recursion over the expression and replace a symbol with a number if the symbol matches. Then `subst-all` could use `subst` as a helper function.

(With this way, how would you know if there is an unbound identifier?)

The second way is to follow your code template:

```
(define struct const (symbol number))

(define (eval t env)
  (cond
    [(number? t) t]
    [(symbol?  t) ???]
    [else ((cond
            [(equal? (second t) '+) +]
            [(equal? (second t) '-) -]
            [(equal? (second t) '*) *]
            [(equal? (second t) '/) /])
           (eval (first t) env) (eval (third t) env))]))
```

Canonically, the second argument of this function (such as `(list (make-const 'x 1) (make-const 'y 2))`) is known as *environment*. When you see a symbol, you just lookup on the environment and return the value that associates with the symbol that you are looking up.

```
; lookup :: symbol, listof const -> number
(define (lookup sym env)
  (cond
   [(empty? env) ???]
   [else (if (equal? sym (const-symbol (first env)))
             ??? ; you want to return the value!
             ??? ; recursively call lookup on the rest of the environment
             )]))
```

(With this way, how would you know if there is an unbound identifier?)

See also:

- http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs173/2012/book/adding-functions.html
- http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs173/2012/book/From_Substitution_to_Environments.html